# split method isn't working

Tags: java

I am trying to split a string, but it doesn't work. I debugged my app and I found that the problem was occurring on line 8. On line 8 it shows a document which is named `pattern.class` & the app stopped working. I can't see any problem in my code; I have just followed the rules.

How can I resolve this?

My code:

```
String AdsIds[]=new String[6];
String EnTitle[]=new String[6];
String AdsTemproryData[]=new String[6];
String BineryTemprory[]=new String[2];
public void sieve(String Hash){         
    AdsTemproryData=Hash.split("/");
    for(int i=0;i<=5;i++){
        BineryTemprory= AdsTemproryData[i].split("*");
        AdsIds[i]=BineryTemprory[0];
        EnTitle[i]=BineryTemprory[1];
    }
```

Comment: which exception does the application throw? add the stacktrace to your question. What does your hash look like?

Comment: Why is the question in upper case?  Are you shouting at me?

Comment: @Alex  different cultures

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to escape the asterisk:
`split(\\*)`
So your code will be:

```
String AdsIds[]=new String[6];
String EnTitle[]=new String[6];
String AdsTemproryData[]=new String[6];
String BineryTemprory[]=new String[2];
public void sieve(String Hash){         
            AdsTemproryData=Hash.split("/");
            for(int i=0;i<=5;i++){
                BineryTemprory= AdsTemproryData[i].split("\\*");
                AdsIds[i]=BineryTemprory[0];
                EnTitle[i]=BineryTemprory[1];
            }
```